# I switched out the Orb "on" him

Tags: prepositions

> Peter Quill: He is gonna be so pissed when he realizes I switched out the Orb **on** him.
>
> Gmora: He was gonna kill you, Peter.
>
> Peter Quill: I know. But he was about the only family I had.
>
> Gmora: No. He wasn't.
>
> -- Guardians.of.the.Galaxy.2014

[image]

Although I fully understand what this dialogue is all about, I'm wondering what the usage of **on** is here.

I think **on** indicates who is the recipient of the action.

Can you please give me some more examples?

Comment: To *this* native speaker, the ***on*** usage above is perfectly natural and commonplace. But I've absolutely no idea what *switching out the Orb* means. And even if I knew what "the Orb" was, I think most likely I'd expect it to be either *switched **on*** or *switched **off***. The speaker presumably avoids using ***off*** because it would clash with the immediately-following ***on*** used in a completely different sense, but I'd still say the usage ***switch out*** is relatively non-standard.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, this example of "switched out" is an informal phrasal verb meaning "replaced" or "swapped".  Peter gave his former captian a fake Orb.

Comment: @Gary: You have prior knowledge that an Orb here is something that could be swapped for a "fake" Orb. Without that knowledge it's more reasonable for me to assume Orbs are things that can be switched on or off (like lights). Since it's a sci-fi context, one might even contrive that the Orb is a kind of light bulb. And that Quill swapped an Orb emitting ***visible** [to humans] **light*** for one that only emitted UV-light, say. Which might be specifically intended for use by certain aliens who use that part of the EMF spectrum to see.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I agree.  That's why I commented.  To understand "switched out", you'd either have to know the context (as in, watch the movie and see the results of the swap) or speak a dialect where "switched out" is a common phrasal verb.  I don't expect that you (or most readers, for that matter) would have that context unless a comment like mine provides it.  I did not mean to imply that you *should* have known.  I only meant to imply that you probably *couldn't* have known unless I told you.

Comment: @Gary: Yeah. I suppose I'd have to classify *switched **out*** there as a somewhat "dialectal" usage, since I myself would rarely if ever include the preposition in such contexts. And there have to be at least two "Orbs" for any such action to be undertaken, so my preferred form would probably be *"I switched Orbs on him"* anyway. Whatever - the specific point being queried here is the ***on** [victim / "patient" of action performed by "agent"]*, which is well covered by both answers as I write.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I played a trick on her.

I went Jackie Chan (or Chuck Norris) on him (also on his ass): I used martial arts on him.

My car died on me.

*21. Informal. so as to disturb or affect adversely:*
My hair dryer broke on me.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/on

Comment: This might be even clearer in contrast.  The statement "I replaced the Orb *for* him" means that the replacement is beneficial to him.  The statement "I replaced the Orb *on* him" means that the replacement is detrimental to him.

Comment: That's a point! @GaryBotnovcan

Comment: BTW, can **against** be used instead? I played a trick **against** her.  I used martial arts **against** him. Any nuances? @GaryBotnovcan Jim Reynolds

Comment: Hmm. Not with tricked. *I played a trick on xxx* or *I tricked xxx*. But use (weapon/tactic) against is ok.

Comment: In my dialect, "played a trick against her" works, but doesn't feel completely natural.  I find it more idiomatic to say "played a trick on her".  "I used martial arts against him" is perfectly natural, but "I went 'Bruce Lee' against him" isn't.  "My car died against me" either makes no sense or simply doesn't mean the same thing.  It seems that this sense of "on" is synonymous with this sense of "against", but that "on" is licensed more often.

Comment: In "she looks down **on** anyone who hasn't had a university education." and "they've been holding out **on** me.", are the two **on** the same as those in the following examples? @GaryBotnovcan Jim

Comment: @KinzleB *Look down on* differs, comprising a multiword item--a phrasal verb--replaceable with *disdain* (v.) or *disparage.* And *hold out on* also differs, being replaceable with *conceal.* The *on* discussed above, in contrast, is seperable as a preposition. This compares to *look up* (find) vs. look up (verb + preposition of direction).

Comment: I have to agree with Jim that those are fixed idioms.  For instance, "to look down for" uses a different sense of "to look".  I also have to agree with @KinzleB that these examples use the same sense of "on".  The object of the "on" does get the detriment of the looking down or the holding out.

Answer (score 3):

Best simple substitution example I can think of would be

> "I played a trick on him"

Your example is, I would say, very idiomatic; colloquial, I'd even call it 'hip-speak' especially considering the source.
The entire "switched out [object] on him" I would tend to think of as US Eng, though at modern rates of adoption that might be hard to prove.

My attempts to get an NGRAM have proven fruitless.