# Phrase "get blamed on"

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

Excerpted from [The New Yorker](http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2015/11/23/writers-in-the-storm):

> Melodramatic or banal prose mostly **gets blamed on** the author, reasonably enough.

Something *gets blamed* means someone blames that something, and someone *blamed on* something means something is being blamed by that someone, but what is *get blamed on*?

Comment: *on* tells you who got blamed (it is the object of the blame).

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40810/i-switched-out-the-orb-on-him

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ditransitive verbs (those which normally have a direct and an indirect object) often have two different passives. So "I gave John the book" has passives "The book was given to John [by me]" and "John was given the book [by me]".

In the case of "blame", the prepositions used are anomalous:

> John blames me for the trouble.
>
> I was blamed [by John] for the trouble.

but

> The trouble was blamed **on** me [by John].

Colloquially, we often use forms of "get" for passives instead of forms of "be".

So

> Melodramatic or banal prose ... gets blamed on the author

is a passive of

> [Somebody] blames the author for melodramatic or banal prose.

Comment: +1 Sure is a pleasure seeing you over here on the light side.

Answer (score 5):

*Blame* as a verb assigns responsibility to an agent for a deplorable fact or act. There are two different constructions:

1) with the agent as direct object and the fact or act as object of the  preposition *for*

> He blames her for his brother's death.
>   He blames her for betraying his brother.

2) with the fact or act as direct object and the agent as object of the preposition *on*

> He blames his brother's death on her.
>   He blames his brother's betrayal on her.

In the passive, you re-cast the active direct object as the subject, so with *blame* the construction you use is the one in which your subject is the active direct object. In your example, the subject is the deplorable fact *melodramatic or banal prose*, so you use the *on* construction.

> We blame melodramatic or banal prose **on** the author.  →
>   Melodramatic or banal prose gets blamed **on** the author.

<sub>The first part of this answer is quoted from my Answer to an earlier question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/57770/32).</sub>

Comment: How do you think about following sentence that seems more natural to me? "Melodramatic prose on the author gets blamed." Do you think this structure is wrong?

Comment: @JBL It's wrong, unless you're composing comic songs and want to set up a rhyme on 'blamed'.